# MySQL using all RAM

Tags: 16.04, server, mysql

I am trying to restore SQL dump file of around 750 MB on Ubuntu 16.04 VM with 1GB RAM and MySQL 5.7.21.

I have configured `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 768MB`, `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size = 128M` and `innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 1`.

To stop killing from OOM-killer `OOMScoreAdjust=-1000` is added to `mysql.sqevice` file.

When restoring is started mysqld utilized all memory.

```
root@IA6-OA-DB-01:~# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            987         925          11           0          50          19
Swap:           632         621          11
```

It starts to kill all processes.

```
root@IA6-OA-DB-01:~# mysql -uroot -proot -D OA2017 < OA2017.sql
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Killed
```

Syslog

```
Apr 14 13:13:35 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84990.058935] Out of memory: Kill process 24895 (mysql) score 17 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:35 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84990.477043] Out of memory: Kill process 2226 (sssd_be) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:35 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84990.747574] Out of memory: Kill process 2283 (sssd_be) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:36 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84990.903214] Out of memory: Kill process 1587 (smbd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:36 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84990.971431] Out of memory: Kill process 1587 (smbd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:36 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84991.208088] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:36 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84991.329594] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:38 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84993.369239] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:39 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84994.124215] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:41 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84995.928253] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:44 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84999.295787] Out of memory: Kill process 1587 (smbd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:48 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85003.091554] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:49 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85003.498436] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:50 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85005.624213] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:55 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85007.717901] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:02 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85014.623037] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:02 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85016.130481] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:02 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85017.218094] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:09 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85024.577427] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:09 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85024.857977] Out of memory: Kill process 321 (systemd-journal) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:11 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85025.128881] Out of memory: Kill process 14831 (bash) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:11 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85025.173233] Out of memory: Kill process 14831 (bash) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:34 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85048.414654] Out of memory: Kill process 15546 (bash) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:34 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85048.545329] Out of memory: Kill process 1057 (nginx) score 1 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:34 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85049.430812] Out of memory: Kill process 15513 (sshd) score 1 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:46 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85060.595291] Out of memory: Kill process 1629 (sshd) score 1 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:46 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85060.884189] Out of memory: Kill process 1629 (sshd) score 1 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:46 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85061.268085] Out of memory: Kill process 1061 (nginx) score 1 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:46 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85061.470392] Out of memory: Kill process 1280 ((sd-pam)) score 1 or sacrifice child
```

After this VM gets rebooted.
What could be the problem? and What variables do i need to change to make it run?

Comment: It would be interesting to know how the dump file is structured. Is it in the form of series of `insert` statements or is it one huuuuuge `insert` statement 749MiB large?

Comment: It is database dump file with around 60 tables and bulk insert statements.

Comment: Does this innodb_buffer_pool_size leave enough memory for the rest of the system? Did you try to reduce this value?

Comment: I tried to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_size but still it utilizes all RAM.

Comment: @Shivaditya find the length of the longest line in the dump file: `wc -L OA2017.sql`  This will give us somewhere to start.

Comment: Longest line have `17308871` characters.